# How to solve $\int (2x^2 + 1) e^{x^2} \, dx$ using elementary integration and integration by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\int (2x^2+1)e^{x^2} \, dx$$

It's part of my homework, and I have tried a few things but it seems to lead to more difficult integrals. I'd appreciate a hint more than an answer but all help is valued.

Comment: If you know that $(x\exp(x^{2}))'=(2x^{2}+1)\exp(x^{2})$, so you can say $$\int (2x^2+1)e^{x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x=\int (x\exp(x^{2}))' \, \mathrm{d}x=x\exp(x^{2})+\kappa$$ for all $\kappa\in \mathbb{R}$. I don't know if it's allowed for you to show that way.

Comment: As a hint, find the first few terms of the series expansion (five, so up to $x^8$, should be more than enough), integrate them, spot the pattern, adopt a hypothesis for the integral, and differentiate the likely integral to check it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$  Write the integral as $\int2x^2e^{x^2}dx+\int e^{x^2}dx$.

Then use integration by parts on the first integral, with $dv=2xe^{x^2}dx$

Comment: I see. I did not work out the details.

Answer (score 3):

Start by expanding the integrand.

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int \left(2x^2e^{x^2}+e^{x^2}\right)\,dx\\
&=\int 2x^2e^{x^2}\,dx+\int {e^{x^2}}\,dx\tag{a}\\
&=x e^{x^2}-\int 2x^2 e^{x^2}\,dx+\int 2x^2 e^{x^2}\,dx\\
&=x e^{x^2}+C
\end{align}$$

$(\text{a})$: Use integration by parts on the second integral with $u=e^{x^2}$ and $dv=dx$.

Comment: I think it would be best if you mentioned which integral you used IBP to (since there are two on that line).

Answer (score 2):

Let $u = xe^{x^2}$. Then $du = (2x^2+1) e^{x^2}$.
Thus,

$$\int (2x^2 + 1)e^{x^2} = \int du = u + C = xe^{x^2} + C$$

Comment: I tried a different method and then changed and forgot to change it. Thanks!

Answer (score -4):

Here is a hint; you can not analytically evaluate $\int \exp(x^2) dx$. 
Read more about that on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).
So your final answer should contain terms with $\int \exp(x^2) dx$.

Comment: This is not true. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[%282+x^2+%2B+1%29+E^x^2%2C+x]).

Comment: My bad. In general it is something to watch out for though.